# How to include app urls to project urls in Django 1.8?

Tags: python, django, url

I have just started with django now and was configuring urls. I am able to map different urls like /posts, /posts/create etc. Somehow I am not able to configure root url, I am not sure what wrong I am doing. Here is my configuration :

```
urlpatterns = [
# Examples:
url(r'',homeViews.posts),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^posts/',homeViews.posts),
url(r'^createPost/',homeViews.createPost),
url(r'^createUser/',userViews.createUser),
url(r'^post/(?P<title>[a-z,A-Z]+)/$',homeViews.post),
]`
```

Cheers!

Comment: Here you go- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-include

Answer (score 1):

here is an example, my friend.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'home.views.home',name='index'),
    url(r'^contactanos/$', 'home.views.contacto',name='contacto'),
    url(r'^post/$', 'home.views.blog',name='blog')  
]
```